# Taking Class as an Input

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

The code that I have written is below;

```
class Car:
    color = None
class Motorcycle:
    color = None

class_x = input("Which class do you want to change the color of ? ")

color = input("What color do you want the class object to have ? ")

def change_color(class_x, color):
       class_x.color = color

change_color(class_x, color)

print(class_x.color)
```

Basically, I am trying to allow the user to choose the class whose color he wants to change.

But there is an attribute error. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_x` is a string, it doesn't refer to the class itself,
you can create a mapping between a class and its string name and access it that way

```py
class Car:
    color = None
class Motorcycle:
    color = None

string_to_class = {
    "Car": Car,
    "Motorcycle": Motorcycle
}

class_x = input("Which class do you want to change the color of ? ")

color = input("What color do you want the class object to have ? ")

def change_color(class_x, color):
       class_x.color = color

chosen_class = string_to_class[class_x]
change_color(chosen_class, color)

print(chosen_class.color)
```